# Is "The more training data the better" true for Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-network

I'm programing a function approximation neural network, that is trying to approximate a very complicated function.

For the training data I generated 1000 random numbers between two limits, I then passed these numbers through a function f(x), and got the outputs.

My neural network aims to approximate the inverse of this function. So, I will use the output of the function as the input training data, and the 1000 random numbers as the output training data.

The problem is that when a random number is put into the function f(x), it is much more likely that the output will be between 0 and 0.01, and very very rare that it will fall outside of this range. Below is a number line, with the 1000 numbers from the output of the function plotted on top of it. As you can see the examples do not uniformly cover the full range of possible numbers.

[image: Distribution of 1000 training examples]

To combat this I used a lot of training examples in hope that there will be more examples in the 0.1 to 0.9 range, but this means using a ridiculous number of examples.

So for functions like this, is it just better to use more examples, or are there problems that will arise if you use a huge amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get rid of everything above 0.01, and then normalize your data from 0 to 0.01 into -1 to 1. Since there are so few datapoints above 0.01, removing them won't affect the training.

Alternatively, try this:

> I recommend normalizing independent numeric data by computing the
>   means and standard deviation of the numeric x data, then applying the
>   transform (x - mean) / stddev.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/neural-network-data-normalization-and-encoding.aspx

You want to spread out the clustered data more evenly along the range 0 to 1 (or -1 to 1).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible trying to fit the logarithm or some logarithm-based transforms of f(x)? It may distribute your output more uniformly.

Answer (score -1):

"More is better" only up to a point; you can have too much data for a Neural Network.

You risk over-fitting/over-training with too many samples.

Comment: Overfitting is caused by too much training (too many iterations/epochs), not too much data. With a huge dataset, even one that's far bigger than necessary and with lots of noise, if you exit training at a suitable point, the network will be accurate.

Comment: This is what I thought. If anything a large dataset should reduce the chance of overfitting. Overfitting is caused by the value of the cost function being minimised to such a low value, that the function of the neural network will pass almost exactly through all of the training points (causing the cost function to be low), but not approximate the trend of the points in other areas. Using more training points should reduce the chance of this happening.